# Add section to URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, url

A URL can have a `#sectionName` component, which directs to the part of the site where that section begins.

In Swift I am trying to add that component, but it does not work. I am trying:

```
let url = URL(string: "example.com/component1")!
```

Later I am trying to do:

```
url.appendingPathComponent("#sectionName")
```

but it returns `example.com/component1%23sectionName` instead of `example.com/component1#sectionName`.

At the time the URL is created I still don't have the name of the section, so I can't do `URL(string: "example.com/component1#sectionName")`

I've also tried escaping the `#` with `\#` or `\\#`, but it does not work. Any ideas how to add a component that is a section?

Comment: [`Fragment identifier`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) **is not `path component`**, so it's not right to use `.appendingPathComponent()` here. You should start with [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *`#sectionName` component* is not a path component and you cannot use `appendingPathComponent`.

You may need to use `URLComponent` and add `fragment`:

```
var urlCompo = URLComponents(string: "example.com/component1")!
urlCompo.fragment = "sectionName"
let url = urlCompo.url!
print(url) //->example.com/component1#sectionName
```

Answer (score 2):

When building URLs, I recommend you use [(NS)URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents) instead of manually.

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "example.com"
components.path = "/component1"
components.fragment = "sectionName"

let url = components.url
```

Comment: @regina_fallangi my path was wrong (it needs a starting slash). I have fixed it and tested it myself and it works now.